# Microsoft upgrade assistance tool : can I use this tool to upgrade ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API to .NET 6?

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-2.1

My project is an API built with .NET Core 2.1. I need to convert to .NET 6 using the Microsoft Upgrade Assistance tool. I am not sure if I can do this or not.

Also, after upgrading the project using this tool, do I need to do any manual code changes in `Programme.cs` and `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Well - why don't you just simply **try it** and see ?`

Comment: I tried and couldn't see any code changes. it has only converted project from 2.1 to net 6.  I can see lots of obsolete code is present after migrating. So should I change it manually?

Comment: Update an existing ASP.NET Core 2.1 project to ASP.NET Core 6.0, like this: 2.1 to 3.0 => 3.0 to 3.1 => 3.1 to 5.0 => 5.0 to 6.0